# Application_AuthenticateRequest infinite loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, global-asax

I recently added Forms-based Authentication to an MVC 3 project.  There seems to be a problem between my Application_AuthenticateRequest function(Global.asax.cs file) and my settings for my Web.Config file because my Application_AuthenticateRequest function seems to get called infinitely.  How can I change my configurations for this to work properly and how can I allow a user access to both the login page and the default page, while still denying access to the other pages?

```
    //Global.asax.cs
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Extract the forms authentication cookie
        string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
        HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

        if (null == authCookie)
        {
            // There is no authentication cookie.
            return;
        }

        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;
        try
        {
            authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log exception details (omitted for simplicity)
            return;
        }

        if (null == authTicket)
        {
            // Cookie failed to decrypt.
            return;
        }

        string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split('|');

        // Create an Identity object
        FormsIdentity id = new FormsIdentity(authTicket);

        // This principal will flow throughout the request.
        UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(id, roles);
        // Attach the new principal object to the current HttpContext object
        Context.User = principal;
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
}

//Web.Config
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" 
         protection="All"
         cookieless="UseCookies"
         slidingExpiration="false"
         timeout="30" />
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the comments on Rob's answer...

> "So technically, I need all pages blocked except for default, login and registration pages."

You can add the `AuthorizeAttribute` to the [GlobalFilterCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.globalfiltercollection%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) which is a collection of filters that get applied to all actions on controllers. Then, on your controllers or actions you can add `[AllowAnonymous]` to the specific ones you want anyone to access. See below for an example.

**Create a file called FIlterConfig.cs in the App_Start folder**

*If this exists already, just add the line: `filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());`*

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

This will require every Controller and Action to use Authorization by default.

**You can make a Controller or Action not authorized by adding the following to your Action or Controller like so.**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class MyController
{
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

*All actions in that controller will be available.*

**OR**

```
public class MyController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

*Only that action on the controller will be available.*

Comment: I am having one problem with this approach.  When I remove Forms Authentication from Web.Config, Request.IsAuthenticated seems to always return true.  There are areas of certain pages that I would like to hide depending upon the value of the variable.  How can I make sure Request.IsAuthenticated has the right value?

Comment: When using the Authorize attribute you should have the Forms Authentication in there. If you have a public view and want to hide certain content, you should use something like `@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { authenticated stuff on page here }` in the view.

Answer (score 1):

This will be called for every request, not just when the user logs in for the first time.

You can use the `[Authorize]` attribute to limit access to certain controllers or even methods.

I'd suggest looking through some tutorials or the documents to understand how authentication works in MVC:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: When the user first goes to the default page, they should be redirected to the register page for registration purposes.  So technically, I need all pages blocked except for default, login and registration pages.  Does that mean I would have to add the Authorize attribute to every other page?  Also, if this is the case, where would I verify the authentication ticket?

Comment: Again, I would suggest reading through the Walkthrough. But you would add the [Authorize] attribute to everything that can only be accessed by someone who is logged in. You can add it to the entire Controller (which in turn makes all methods in the Controller need authorization) or just on the method itself.